# How do I efficiently construct a block matrix of the following form in JULIA?

Tags: matrix, julia

So I am working on a code that requires me to construct a large Matrix **M**
using smaller 'square' matrices *J* AND *M* of sizes n x n each, repeated such that:

[image: This is what the matrix should look like!]

i.e with the dimensions of **M** such that *M* is repeated 'L' times along the diagonal, *J'* is repeated along the upper second diagonal and *J* on the lower second diagonal.

Note that I am working on Julia v 1.0.0 and as far as I understand there are no direct ways of assigning Block Matrices in Julia, unlike *Mathematica*.

I tried to use Kronecker products to solve my problem:

```
 =Diagonal(ones(L)) #IDENTITY matrix of L x L size
 =kron(,M)
```

Doing so, I can make a Block diagonal matrix **M** with small matrix *M* repeated along its diagonal. But now how do I place matrices J and *J'* along its second diagonals as required?

Answer (score 9):

[BlockArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/BlockArrays.jl) (and maybe [BlockBandedMatrices.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/BlockBandedMatrices.jl)) should be what you are looking for as it makes handling block matrix structures very convenient.

An example (with `Strings`s):

```
julia> using BlockArrays

julia> M = fill("M", 2,2);

julia> J = fill("J", 2,2);

julia> B = BlockArray{String}(undef_blocks, [2,2], [2,2])
4×4 BlockArray{String,2,Array{String,2}}:
 #undef  #undef  │  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  │  #undef  #undef
 ────────────────┼────────────────
 #undef  #undef  │  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  │  #undef  #undef

julia> setblock!(B, M, 1,1);

julia> setblock!(B, M, 2,2);

julia> setblock!(B, J, 1,2);

julia> setblock!(B, J, 2,1);

julia> B
4×4 BlockArray{String,2,Array{String,2}}:
 "M"  "M"  │  "J"  "J"
 "M"  "M"  │  "J"  "J"
 ──────────┼──────────
 "J"  "J"  │  "M"  "M"
 "J"  "J"  │  "M"  "M"
```

For more information, check out the package's [documentation](http://juliaarrays.github.io/BlockArrays.jl/stable/).

Comment: If you just want the matrix you can use literal syntax too: `[M J; J M]`

Comment: The matrix that I want to construct is actually a very large one, so the literal syntaxing is not possible. However like user @crstnbr said I might be able to use the BlockArrays package to construct a function to define such a matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without any external packages like this:

```
# assign stand-in values
L = 4;
n = 2;
M = reshape(1:n^2, (n, n));
J = -M;

# put together the larger matrix
μ = [zeros(Int64, n, n) for i in 1:L, j in 1:L];
μ[diagind(μ)] .= [M];
μ[diagind(μ, -1)] .= [J];
μ[diagind(μ, 1)] .= [J'];
bM = reduce(vcat, [reduce(hcat, μ[i, :]) for i in 1:L]);
```

The final matrix `bM` is then:

```
8×8 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   3  -1  -2   0   0   0   0
  2   4  -3  -4   0   0   0   0
 -1  -3   1   3  -1  -2   0   0
 -2  -4   2   4  -3  -4   0   0
  0   0  -1  -3   1   3  -1  -2
  0   0  -2  -4   2   4  -3  -4
  0   0   0   0  -1  -3   1   3
  0   0   0   0  -2  -4   2   4
```

Not sure how the effiency compares to other answers, but it may at least be nice to know it can be done without too much complication.

Answer (score 0):

The `Tridiagonal` function from the [Linear Algebra](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.Tridiagonal) package gives the desired result.

**Example**:

```
dl = ones(5)
du = ones(5) * 2
d = ones(5 + 1) * 3

Tridiagonal(dl, d, du)
```

**Result**:

```
6×6 Tridiagonal{Float64, Vector{Float64}}:
 3.0  2.0   ⋅    ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
 1.0  3.0  2.0   ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅   1.0  3.0  2.0   ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅    ⋅   1.0  3.0  2.0   ⋅ 
  ⋅    ⋅    ⋅   1.0  3.0  2.0
  ⋅    ⋅    ⋅    ⋅   1.0  3.0
```

If you are looking for a symetric tridiagonal matrix, you can use `SymTridiagonal` from the same package.

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for a way to have _matrices_ along the three diagonals, not _floats_.